# angularJS there is data in scope, but I can't get them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I write a directive, there is `data` in $scope, but in my directive, in `link` function, I can get data with `scope.data`
but I console.log(scope), there really has `data` in scope, but I cant get `data`

**there is directive.js:**

```
  todoApp.directive('planProgress', function() {
    return {
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        attrs.$set('value', 10);
        attrs.$set('total', 20);
        elem.progress();
      }
    };
  });
```

**result in console with chrome:**

```
data: Array[3]
```

But if I `console.log(scope.data)` in directive.js, this is `undefined` in console.log
I don't why, can directive inherit of controller?

Comment: `scope: false` is the default, it means the directive does not create a new scope, and it should see the scope which is created in. You probably have other HTML code and scoping issues that you don't show us that's getting in the way.

Comment: My guess is that your directive is wrapped by another directive with isolated scope

Comment: Can you share a plunker to show the issue?

Comment: Show the code where `$scope.data` is set. I'm guessing that it arrives later than when you `console.log` it.

Comment: @NewDev  I `console.log(scope)` ther is `data` in console.log, But If I `console.log(scope.data)` there is `undefined` in console

Comment: @nataila, yes, I understood from your question. You have to understand that `console.log` doesn't show what the logged object was at "log-time", but at "display-time"